# Best way to store hourly data with redis

Tags: database, redis, statistics

I would like to store hourly the amount of money the users are spending. But I don't know which would be the best way to do it or the best data structure to use.

I thought about a hash with user_id:YYYYMMDD and then hours elements into, like the following:

```
Bsjdyebs8yb58b:2014:04:07
-- 01 : 215$
-- 02 : 8719$
-- 03 : 942$
-- ...
-- 23 : 100$

Jsbjub75458b:2014:04:07
-- 01 : 5$
-- 02 : 89$
-- 03 : 42$
-- ...
-- 23 : 10$
```

Comment: Sorry, every -- should be in a new line to show the content of each hash.

Comment: How do you want to use stored data?

Comment: I want to update constantly the spent money and then get all the data when the day ends.

Answer (score 2):

There's a command to atomically increment the value in a hash. It's called **[HINCRBYFLOAT](http://redis.io/commands/hincrbyfloat)**.

Every time a user spends, you should execute this:

```
HINCRBYFLOAT usr.dailySpending.user_id YYYMMDDHH moneyAmount
```

This is the command your program should execute when the user `Bsjdyebs8yb58b` is spending  $20.50 today at 4PM:

```
HINCRBYFLOAT usr.dailySpending.Bsjdyebs8yb58b 2014040816 20.50
```

When you want to read the value, the command would be:

```
HMGET usr.dailySpending.Bsjdyebs8yb58b 2014040816
```

Comment: Good one, the OP is only interested in the cumulated amount, so this is most probably the best answer. The OP might have to split by currency though, but that's trivial if needed. Tiny addition: the user asked for YYYMMDDHH. Again, trivial. +1

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer to hourly expenses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hashes are good way to do that. You can build something like that:

```
HSET user:1000 2014-04-07:01 "10$"
HSET user:1000 2014-04-07:02 "50$"
HSET user:1000 2014-04-07:03 "40$"
```

More information about Hashes:

http://redis.io/commands#hash

Comment: Why do you write user: ?

Comment: It's just for an example. You can replace your user:xxxx with your user_id  or any other identifier.

Comment: I created date:time format to organize the data. I believe this is the most organized way to build the data you want.

Comment: So, your approximation is having a hash that contains dates where each one has a spent value, right? Why not id+date for the key value?

Comment: Yes. Date:time is your key and spend amounth is value.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a `ZSET`.

```
ZADD user:1000 2014040701 "<uniquefier> 10$"  
ZADD user:1000 2014040701 "<uniquefier> 10$"
ZADD user:1000 2014040701 "<uniquefier> 20$"
```

For the `<uniquefier>` (which you **need** because of the unicity of a member in a sorted set), you can use several things:

1. A sequence per user via `HSET` and `HINCRBY`
2. A session id + session sequence which you might have at hand already
3. A timestamp in 'ticks' (if that is enough precision, take care)
4. A guid

This setup scales well, and via a `ZRANGEBYSCORE` you can immediately get all sorted set members of that timestamp-hour.

If you combine this with the upcoming `ZRANGEBYLEX`, and swap the uniquefier / amount$, you can do all kinds of crazy lookups, the sky *(well, maybe up until the cloud)* is the limit.

Cheers, TW

Word of caution: be careful when using more than 15 digits for the `SCORE`, in case you'd like to store per-minute or per-second or per-millisecond. You will loose precision; the SCORE is a float. To be more precise: a IEEE 753 FP double.